# Remove/hide accessibility info from tooltip in Chrome developer tool

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

In Google Chrome version 65 the tooltip with DOM id and size was as in this picture: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/images/2018/01/a11y-pane.png

But now they have added info about "accessibility". And I dont need that info and waste space.

How I go back to previous design?

Comment: There's no way in stable Chrome currently. It'll be [fixed in Chrome 85](https://crbug.com/1092841), currently dev channel.